# ClusterID vs JobFlowID on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, emr

I am a bit confused about the APIs available and the two identifiers.
I am using boto, but don't think that is the problem here : my question regards any api (but not cli).

I start a JobFlow with RunJobFlow which returns me a JobFlowId. Let's assume I don't want to keep the number, but rather find later what JobFlows are running to add steps to them.

I think I should be able to use DescribeJobFlows, to find all jobflow_ids and proceed from there. But on documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_DescribeJobFlows.html) this api call is marked as deprecated, and directs us to use ListClusters, which returns cluster_ids.

What ties the 2 together ? Is it the same identifier ? If not how can I get jobflows ids from the cluster id ?

I think the confusion also comes by the fact that on cli the command is "create-cluster" and that returns a cluster_id, and add-steps also takes a cluster_id....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The cluster id and job flow id are the same thing (j-######).  A cluster id is a more appropriate name to its purpose as to not be confused with the terminology of a job as seen with Hadoop. So go ahead and use ListClusters (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_ListClusters.html).

Comment: thank you very much. The terminology is very confusion.